# preg_match form and get name of field

Tags: php, forms, preg-match

I have multi forms like this:

```
$string = '

Form number 1
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="pn" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Form number 2
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/home.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="y" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Form number 3
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="x" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Form number 4
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/contact.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="c" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Form number 5
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="v" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
Form number 6
<form class="form-search" method="post" action="/index.php?a=v">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="address_box" type="text" class="form-control" name="k" value="" onfocus="this.select()" />
  </div>
<span class="btn btn-s btn-caps"><input type="submit" value="start" /></span>
</form>
';
```

I want to:

```
Preg_match:
START = <form

WHERE action CONTAIN /index.php but nothing after it
EX: action="/index.php" or action="http://whatever.com/index.php"
    can't be action="/index.php?s=w"

FIND name="[A-Za-z]{1}"

END = </form>
```

Repeat it for each form until find the (first) matched form Then Output the [A-Za-z]{1} Match

Here is the code:

```
$pat = '~<form[^>]+action="[^"]*/(?:index.php)"[^>]*>.*?name="([a-zA-Z]{1})".*?</form>~s';
preg_match($pat,$string,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

It should select the matched form (number 3) and output = x

But i'm getting output = y (form number 2)

Any help please?

Thanks.

Comment: None of the forms has a `name` attribute in your example.

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the title of the question, thanks.

Comment: Do you want to get all input field names?

Comment: No, just for the (first) correct matched form, where action contain "index.php" + nothing after it and name="[A-Za-z]{1}" then output [A-Za-z]{1}

Comment: use xpath: `//form[contains(@action, "index.php")]//input[matches(@name, /[A-Z-a-z]/)`

Comment: Thank you, but is there is any chance with preg_match?

Comment: XPath is the way to go here: It's reliable, maintainable and simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath way:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$query = '//form[substring(@action, string-length(@action) - 10) = "/index.php"]'
       . '/div/input/@name[string-length(.)=1]';

$nameList = $xp->query($query);

foreach($nameList as $nameNode) {
    $char = $nameNode->nodeValue;
    $ascii = ord(strtolower($char));
    // check if it is a letter with its ascii code
    if ($ascii < 123 && $ascii > 60) {
        $result = $char;
        break;
    }
}

echo $result;
```

XPath is designed to target one or several elements in the DOM tree (a tree representation of the html document). So, `//elt1/elt2/elt3` defines the path (where elt1, elt2... are tags) and all that is between square brackets are conditions for the current node.

```
//    # from everywhere in the DOM tree
form  # a form tag
[     # condition for the current element (the form tag):
      # must have an attribute "action" that ends with "/index.php".
      # In other words: the last 10 characters of the "action" attribute
      # must be "/index.php"
  substring(@action, string-length(@action) - 10) = "/index.php"
]

      # lets continue the path until the name attribute of the input tag
/div/input/@name
      # condition for the name attribute
      # . is the current node, it must be one character length
[string-length(.)=1]'
```

Comment: or `//form[contains(@action, "index.php")]//input[matches(@name, "[A-Z-a-z]")]/@name`

Comment: @hek2mgl: contains doesn't suffice, you must emulate `ends-with` (that doesn't exist in XPath1.0).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't have an experience with XPath, but i can see name = "x" (x) which i don't know it..i want to get it.

Comment: @hek2mgl: because the user asks :"WHERE action CONTAIN /index.php but nothing after it".

Comment: @user2203703: Sorry, I have too quickly read the question (my turn), it is corrected now.